# Parsing data back to mainPanel (java/swing)

Tags: java, swing

Set up:
I have a mainPanel with a tabbedPane on it, i have a separate JPanel 'extra', extra creates an objects and i wish to pass that object back through to the mainPanel where i can actually use it/add it to the data structure.

Frame > Panel > TabbedPane > Panel (Separate Class, instantiated as new object)

I tried to add a listener in mainPanel that checks if a boolean in PanelExtra changes and then runs a method etc, but it didn't work.

I would make a method in mainPanel to accept the object but i don't know how to refer back to it. (getRootPane() didn't return anything)

Also im not sure if im using correct terminology, while i was taught Java in a command line Unix environment,  Swing is very new to me.

I tried Listeners, Observers and am currently considering an object created at root and passed DOWN through all objects (As java passes by reference, i could pass information back as far as i want) If that isn't an entirely stupid idea, let me know and we can all go about our lives. If there is a better way to do it that'd be great.

(File overview)

[programApp]>[programView>tabbedPane]>[panel]
Panel is created using new, and exists in a separate class.
I want to pass data back from Panel to programView (projectNameView as it is in netbeans)

I will attempt to add as much information as i can.

Comment: I think the best way is to pass down the JFrame object all the way to the Class with the final JPanel (like you said). It is not neat, but probably the easiest. 

What exactly do you want to do with the Frame?

Comment: You can try and use spring (http://www.springsource.org/) for that - it can handle your case. But it can be an overkill. Anyway i suggest trying the easiest weay - what @Hidde said, or just using some static variable on mainPanel, which will hold your object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [MVC-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) for that.

Actually there are couple of variants depending on your preferences or exact task.
For very simple case you can just use class with static fields to pass objects.
Another way is to define your own listeners like:

```
private myPanel extends JPanel implements Notification {
```

...
and where you create that panel:

```
myPanel.addNotificationReciever(mainPanel);
```

Later you just call `fireNotification` or whatever and implement similar listener for your `mainPanel`.

Comment: It seems like a good idea, but myPanel.addNotificationReciever(mainPanel) (Or any panel, the reference isn't found) doesn't work. I can only .addNotify().

Comment: Yeah, you should create 2 interfaces: let's call them NotificationListener and NotificationSubmiter or whatever. The first one should have one method void onNotification(Object o) and be implemented in your main panel, while later should have 2 methods - addNotificationReciever(NotificationListener) and fireNotification(). Idea behind these two methods: first just stores all listener passed to it in ArrayList while second method iterates over this list and calls method onNotification on each

Comment: Take a look at the short example to illustrate my comment http://pastie.org/2715941

Answer (score 1):

SirVaulterScoff gave the best answer in my opinion, but I thought I'd add some more (can't add comments yet, so I'm creating a new answer).

You should also read the Observer-Observable pattern ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)), which is used along with the MVC pattern. It will be useful when linking your MVC classes together, to make sure everything is as loosely coupled as possible.

As a side comment: MVC is really a pattern you should focus on if you are to create applications with a user interface. It will save you many headaches, and will make your application easier to maintain and extend.